# FaunaDB: How should Document type be imported?

Tags: typescript, node-modules, faunadb

I'd like to make use of the Document type defined in the `faunadb` values module. However, the values module type exports, including Document, are not recognized by the TypeScript compiler.

I can't:

```js
import {values} from "faunadb";

const { Document } = values;
```

Is there another way I should be doing this?

For those who don't know Fauna, but might be able to help with their knowledge of type exports, the Document typescript type is exported as follows:

```js
export module values {

  ...

  export type Document<T = object> = {
    ref: Ref
    ts: number
    data: T
  }

  ...

}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you do this:

```js
const { Document } = values;
```

You try to use the type like it is a value. You can use the `Document` type through the `values` module, though:

```js
type UserDocument = values.Document<{
  name: string
  email: string
}>

const result = await client.query<UserDocument>(
  Get(Ref(Collection("User"), "1234"))
)
```